Ros2 Link library plugin hardware with other library
I need in hardware interface plugin to create object other library. How can I link a library?
add_library(robot_library)

add_library(hardware_library)

I tried using target link libraries, but get error
target_link_libraries(hardware_library robot_library)

Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, 
and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string:
Could not load library dlopen error:
path/librobot_library.so.: undefined symbol: _ZTVN17robot_libarry19RobotLibraryE,

The error occurs when executing the following code
//hardware_library.cpp

robot_library = std::make_shared<robot_library>()


The error was that I tried to inherit the robot_library library class from Node.
There is no need to do that)
